# Horizontally centering elements text-align center not working

Tags: html, text, centering

I'm trying to center the contents in a navigation box but unfortunately the text-align center isn't working as I thought it would. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong with this? When the window is small it's perfect. But for full screens it's not working as I expected(it's not evenly distributed but is packed at the front. I made the width 100% so not sure why centering isn't working. Thank you. I apologize if the indentation looks off because in the edit box it looks way more accurate than that.

```css
#subnav {
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}

#subnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: orange;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid green;
 
}

#subnav li {
    float: left;
}

#subnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#subnav li a:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```

```html
   <div id="subnav">
           
            <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Mom </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Dad </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Grandad </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Grandma </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Auntie </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Uncle </a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Son </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Daughter </a></li>



    </ul>

           </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`text-align` centres the inline content of an element.

`float` causes an element to:

- become a block
- shrinkwrap its contents

… so the text is centred inside the links, which are exactly wide enough to hold the text (so centring the text has no effect).

---

Use `display: inline-block` instead of floating the list items.

Floating is designed to give effects like this:

[image: How floats work]

… not to put a collection of blocks in a row.